# The negation of the continuum hypothesis as an axiom

Tags: set-theory

Suppose that one considers the formal theory "ZFC+~CH", or the set of all axioms of ZFC plus the negation of the continuum hypothesis.  Then we have that there exists at least one set S whose cardinality lies between that of the integers and the real numbers.

Do set theorists know anything about S?  In particular, supposing that S is a subset of R, which elements from R does S contain?  Has there been any research into this?

Comment: Assuming it is false shouldn't change anything. The set can't be constructed with ZFC. Does negating the continuum hypothesis somehow allow the construction of such a set? Seems not, intuitively.

Comment: I agree that it is hard to think of how to construct the set.  But the set must exist.  Could one prove things interesting facts about it?  Surely someone has thought about this before....

Comment: Gödel's theorem states that the continuum hypothesis is undecidable. If such a set could be constructed, Gödel's theorem would be disproved. We don't need to take a position on the continuum hypothesis to prove Gödel's theorem.

Comment: As someone who hasn't studied much set theory, this has always confused me: is it possible to write down some $S$, whose cardinality can't be determined using ZFC? Or is it impossible to even *write down* S without ~CH?

Comment: @user7530 Take the set $WO$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ that are (as binary relations) wellorders of $\mathbb{N}$. Now partition $WO$ into isomorphism classes, obtaining $\Omega$. This $\Omega$ has always the smallest uncountable cardinal. So you can't decide if there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$  and $\Omega$.

Comment: The set of countable ordinals, which can be identified with a subset of the reals via a well-ordering of the reals.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "via a well-ordering of the reals" — any particular well-ordering of the reals? :) If V = L then sure, and in other cases, sure, but in general, as you know but OP probably doesn't, there may not even be a projective well-ordering of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Pedro If $\neg$CH then there is no bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: @BrianO: Well, for sure the "example" mentioned in the comment does not have an explicit character.